# Copy MongoDb indexes between databases

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to copy mongo indexes between two environments. Checked the API and found no direct method of doing it. So I started writing a script that connects to one db, iterates over the collections, grabs indexes, mutates them (because `getIndexes()` and `ensureIndex()`) have different format), connects to the other db, wipes the indexes and copies the new ones in.

This all feels slightly over the top so I think that I must be missing something.

Any suggestions/good practices? Apart from having an index creation strategy.

Cheers!

Comment: Seems reasonable for a one off as you'll probably have an index creation strategy in your future. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please run it on the database that you want to copy indexes.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
indexes.forEach(function (c) {
opt = ''
ixkey = JSON.stringify(c.key, null, 1).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
ns = c.ns.substr(c.ns.indexOf(".") + 1, c.ns.length)
for (var key in c) {
 if (key != 'key' && key != 'ns' && key != 'v') {
 if (opt != '') { opt+= ','}        
 if (c.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if (typeof(c[key]) == "string") {
        opt +=  (key + ': "' + c[key] + '"')
      } else  {
        opt+=  (key + ": " + c[key])
       }
     }
   }
  }
  if (opt != '') { opt = '{' + opt + '}'}
  print ('db.' + ns + '.ensureIndex(' + ixkey + ','+  opt + ')')
 })});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've updated script of Adamo Tonete

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(col) {
    var indexes = db[col].getIndexes();
    indexes.forEach(function (c) {
        var fields = '', result = '', options = {};
        for (var i in c) {
            if (i == 'key') {
                fields = c[i];
            } else if (i == 'name' && c[i] == '_id_') {
                return;
            } else if (i != 'name' && i != 'v' && i != 'ns') {
                options[i] = c[i];
            }
        }
        var fields = JSON.stringify(fields);
        var options = JSON.stringify(options);
        if (options == '{}') {
            result = "db." + col + ".createIndex(" + fields + "); ";
        } else {
            result = "db." + col + ".createIndex(" + fields + ", " + options + "); ";
        }
        result = result
            .replace(/{"floatApprox":-1,"top":-1,"bottom":-1}/ig, '-1')
            .replace(/{"floatApprox":(-?\d+)}/ig, '$1')
            .replace(/\{"\$numberLong":"(-?\d+)"\}/ig, '$1');
        print(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this script:

```
var i, c, 
    co_name, co_new, 
    co_old, co_old_i, 
    _db = db.getSiblingDB('logs'), 
    _colls = ['activity.games', 'activity.session', 'activity.social', 'activity.store'];

for (i in _colls){
    co_name = _colls[i];
    co_old = _db[co_name];
    co_old_i = co_old.getIndexes();
    if(co_old.count() > 0){
        co_old.renameCollection(co_name + '.old');
        _db.createCollection(co_name);  
        co_new = _db[co_name];
        for(c in co_old_i){
            co_new.ensureIndex(co_old_i[c].key);
        }   
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/alejandrobernardis/8261327

Regards,
A

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version to recreate them all with options, and with the new createIndex command instead of ensureIndex (since mongoDB 3.0). With that, it's very easy to copy (recreate) all indexes from one DB to another.

```
function createIndex2( coll, keys, options ) {
    var ret = db[coll].createIndex(keys, options)
    if (ret.createdCollectionAutomatically) print( "Collection " + coll + " was created")
    if (ret.errmsg || (ret.note != "all indexes already exist" && ret.ok != 1)) {
      ret.coll = coll
      ret.keys = keys
      ret.options = options
      print(tojson(ret))      
    } else {
        //print( "Everything normal", JSON.stringify(ret)) 
    }
}

db.getCollectionInfos().forEach(function(coll) {
  //print( JSON.stringify( coll ))
  if (coll.type === "collection" ) {
    db[coll.name].getIndexes().forEach(function(index) {
        if ("_id_" !== index.name) {
            //print( JSON.stringify( index ))
            var indexKey = index.key        // save the key, and transform index into the "options"
            delete index.key
            delete index.ns     // namespace - not necessary
            delete index.v      // not necessary
            index.background = true     // optional: force background to be true
            //native version: print("db." + coll.name + ".createIndex(" + JSON.stringify(indexKey) + ", " + JSON.stringify(index) + ")");
            // this gives much more debug info
            print("createIndex2(\"" + coll.name + "\", " + JSON.stringify(indexKey) + ", " + JSON.stringify(index) + ")");
            }
    });
  }
});
```

The result looks like that if using the "native" version, otherwise, it will display only errors:

> db.dishes.createIndex({"submenu":1},
>   {"name":"submenu_1","ns":"dishly.dishes","background":true})
>   db.dishes.createIndex({"loc":"2dsphere"},
>   {"name":"loc_2dsphere","ns":"dishly.dishes","2dsphereIndexVersion":3,"background":true})
>   db.dishes.createIndex({"rs":-1},
>   {"name":"rs_-1","ns":"dishly.dishes","partialFilterExpression":{"rs":{"$gte":3}},"background":true})
>   db.dishes.createIndex({"loc":"2d","type":1,"status":1,"FSid":1,"rs":-1},
>   {"name":"loc_2d_type_1_status_1_rs_-1","ns":"dishly.dishes","background":true,"partialFilterExpression":{"rs":{"$gte":2}}})
>   db.dishes.createIndex({"_fts":"text","_ftsx":1,"loc.0":1,"loc.1":1,"rs":-1},
>   {"name":"d2_menu_submenu_text__loc__rs","ns":"dishly.dishes","background":true,"weights":{"d2":1,"menu":1,"submenu":1},"default_language":"english","language_override":"language","textIndexVersion":3})